# Is there any impact on the results of random forest if we have perfect separation in the database?

Tags: regression, logistic, random-forest, separation

I'm having a perfect separation in my database.  One of the solutions is to switch randomly some of the values of the dependent variable to the opposite for the variables that cause the problem this can resolve the problem for regression. My question is about the random forest, I want to know if there is an impact also on the results of the random forest algorithm if we have this problem.  Since it's a bagging algorithm, so I cannot guaranty that for some trees we will have perfect separation.

Answer (score 0):

Complete separation shouldn't be a problem for random forest.  Complete separation causes the likelihood function in logistic regression not to have a maximum (and switching labels is not the recommended approach for solving this).  Random forest does not have a likelihood function and hence can not suffer from the same problem.  in fact, if the hyperplane which separates the cases lies in the direction of one of the standard basis vectors, then a random forest might perform very very well.

Comment: @Demitri Pananos, thank you for your reply. So is it still correct to use the initial database without any changes when performing RF?  And use other technics for logistic regression by penalizing the likelihood for example? because I want to build the two models (RF and GLM).